# How to target specific multiple cells when using a subtract/add quantity script in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Here is my spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F0hooJ0Wo62IOgKsGebI8flr7fTmPVIho_FBFAasn_Y/edit?usp=sharing

I currently have a script called inventory as follows

```
function subtractSoldBulk() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  var soldRange = sheet.getRange(3, 3, maxRows); // row, column, number of rows "Sold" column
  var totalRange = sheet.getRange(3, 4, maxRows); // row, column, max rows "Inventory" column

  var soldValues = soldRange.getValues();
  var totalValues = totalRange.getValues();
  for (var row in soldValues) {
    var soldCellData = soldValues[row][0];
    var totalCellData = totalValues[row][0];

    if (soldCellData != "" && totalCellData != "") {
      totalValues[row][0] = totalCellData - soldCellData;
      soldValues[row][0] = "";
    }
  }

  soldRange.setValues(soldValues);
  totalRange.setValues(totalValues);
}


function addBulk() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  var addRange = sheet.getRange(3, 5, maxRows); // row, column, number of rows "Add" column
  var totalRange = sheet.getRange(3, 4, maxRows); // row, column, max rows "Inventory" column

  var addValues = addRange.getValues();
  var totalValues = totalRange.getValues();
  for (var row in addValues) {
    var addCellData = addValues[row][0];
    var totalCellData = totalValues[row][0];

    if (addCellData != "" && totalCellData != "") {
      totalValues[row][0] = totalCellData + addCellData;
      addValues[row][0] = "";
    }
  }

  addRange.setValues(addValues);
  totalRange.setValues(totalValues);
  }
```

This script allows me to use add and subtract buttons on my spreadsheet so that if i put a quantity in the add or sold columns on a particular row, that quantity will be added or subtracted from the Inventory Quantity on the same row once the add or subtract button is pressed. I want to edit this script so that when I put a quantity in the add or subtract columns add press the buttons, that quantity is added or subtracted from more than one cell in the inventory quantity column.

I need to be able to choose which cells the script applies to. For example- subtract 1 from cells b4  e2, e8 when quantity is entered in Sold column in cell c3 and subtract button is pressed.

I would also like to do this multiple times so for example

Subtract quantity from cells b4  e2, e8 when quantity is entered in Sold column in cell c3 and sold button is pressed
Subtract quantity from cells b6  e2, e5 when quantity is entered in Sold column in cell c4 and sold button is pressed
Subtract quantity from cells b9  e1, e7 when quantity is entered in Sold column in cell c5 and sold button is pressed

etc

It should be the same situation for adding quantities

I'm not sure how to get there from the script I have. I feel like I'm halfway there. I'm a beginner when it comes to scripting so please bare this in mind

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Francis

Comment: Each time you click the add/ subtract button you want to be presented with a popup window that will allow you to choose what cells to add/ subtract from?? You mention 'subtract quantity from cells in column B but column B contains text??

Comment: Hi James that was just an example. A better example relating to the sheet would be if I type a 1 (to subtract the quantity of 1 from column D) in cell C3 I would like to be able to choose which cells this targets in column D3. This shouldn't be in the popup window but should be a permanent thing.

Comment: @James Donnellan Ran out of space in last comment.... so How do I edit this script  so I can choose which cells across the sheet it will subtract the quantity from if I enter a number in cell c3 and press the subtract button. and when I enter the quantity 1 in cell c4 and press subtract which cells it will target then, and when I enter the quantity 1 in cell c5 and press subtract which cells it will target then  etc

Comment: Your choice of words is a little bit confusing lol.. You say you 'to be able to choose which cells this targets' and then 'but should be a permanent thing'. Do you mean that you want to hard code these cells into the program? I.e. if you enter a number in cell C3 then it subtracts from D3, D5 & D7 every time If you enter a number in cell C6 then it subtracts from D2, D8 & D11 every time etc??

Comment: That is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: O well that's quite easy then, use a [switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) and hard code in the ranges you need. From looking at the code above it's not of much use to you in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the linked spreadsheet based on the one you provided above.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I5bRqxhI__rh_K57fwQ5fD7Lwj57OePi7M9m8gdcY0w/edit#gid=0)

How to use it:

1. Enter a value in a cell (A cell specified in the ranges array) Note: you must commit the value to the cell i.e. click return or click out of the cell.
2. **Important**: Click on the cell again so that it is the active cell.
3. Click add or subtract button to have the value added or subtracted from the specified values in the inventory column.

Comment: Hi James, I cant edit the sheet and can only comment on it so I can't do anything. Can you change the sharing settings to anyone with the link please?

Comment: @FrancisDuggan, I have changed the settings. For some reason 'Make a copy' is not working on it tho.

Comment: Hi James. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated. The only thing I've noticed is that when subtracting, the final result ends being a negative number when it should be a positive number. I've sorted it. It should be b-a rather than a-b

Comment: Strange, can you give me an example?

Comment: e.g if its a-b and I'm selecting C5 (quanity 5) to subtract that from D5 (quantity 15) then it should be b-a because I'm subtracting 5 from 15 otherwise you end up with a negative number in D5.    One more question James. If I move rows around on the sheet is there any way that I can make it so the script adjusts??

Comment: Ahh apologies, sorry, I just looked back at the old script now!! Am... In short, yes it is, anything is possible really but it will add a lot of complexity (i.e. lines of code) to the script. I wouldn't be able to say without knowing exactly what it is that changes, why it changes and how it changes.

Comment: I think I'll leave it for now. Thanks a lot for all of your help. Is there some way for me to thank you/rep you on here?

Comment: Just under the up and down arrows beside my answer is a green tick, click that, but it won't get me the rep until you gain more rep.